# PHP Inertia framework i didn't find much information from the web

Tags: php, entity-framework

Anyone has any idea about PHP Inertia framework? How do you evaluate it? Google didn't help me to find out it's manuel.

Comment: Unless I'm looking at the wrong "Inertia Framework" is there any reason why you'd want to use a product that has not been updated since October of 2007, has no active development and no community to speak of?

Comment: Well, at least they picked the right name

Answer (score 2):

They are supposed to be at http://inertiamvc.com/docs.htm but it doesn't look like this framework is maintained anymore. The first and only release was in 2007. Their [forum](http://inertiamvc.com/forum/phpBB2/index.php?sid=9d51429156cd2e3469fd1295d7681f56) is full of spam.

You might want to have a look at one of the other frameworks around:

- http://www.phpframeworks.com
- http://php-frameworks.net/

Answer (score 1):

After some google action I found this. http://inertiamvc.com.

I wouldn't recomment using a framework with an unfinished homepage where the latest "test news" is declared to "7th September, 2007". Also the documentation on the homepage is not reachable. Seems like a dead project ...